# NSPredicate between float values(Latitude and Longitude) from CoreData

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a CoreData Entity containing latitude and longitude coordinates. Just want to set a NSPredicate to get records between certain coordintes. This is what I got so far:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lat <= %f AND lat >= %f AND lon <= %f AND lon >= %f",minLat,maxLat,minLon,maxLon];`

This predicate returns no result at all. Then I tried to search with `BETWEEN` condition from `NSArray` with `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:]` objects and got a crash with exception `NSCFNumber` contstantValue unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `minLat,maxLat,minLon,maxLon`=>`maxLat,minLat,maxLon,minLon`. Simple logic issue it seems.

Comment: Just to clarify, as I found out recently, BETWEEN cannot be used with an `NSPredicate` used with `CoreData`, and is the cause of your crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"lat <= %f AND lat >= %f AND lon <= %f AND lon >= %f",
maxLat, minLat, maxLon, minLon];
```